# Protected functions in Scala

Tags: scala

How do you make a protected function in a class accessible to just all classes in the package in Scala?

Comment: When unit testing the internal functionality of a given class the package protected classifier comes really in handy (you don't want to make that complex method public, but you would love to run a unit test for it)

Answer (score 40):

You can do

```
protected[packagename] def foo() {...}
```

Comment: Yes, but lets call that what it is: a method. Functions in Scala are something else entirely.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `private[packagename]`?

Comment: Then this is the answer you were looking for, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 11):

If we pay attention to the distinction between function and method, we can define an object deriving from `Function`:

```
protected[packagename] object fn extends (Int=>Int) {
  def apply(n: Int) = 2*n 
}
```